# how to make an active element in dropdowns with html, css, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have provided a snippet, however the output is different from [here](https://ibb.co/vxn34RD) and so please **beware**. I am trying to achieve where:

1. When the user clicks 'Home 1' under 'Home', it will be an active element
2. In addition, when the user clicks 'Home 2', 'Home 1' will be inactive and 'Home 2' will be an active element

Same goes for the 'Pages' dropdown list. May I know what are the solutions?

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

    #sidebar.active {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
        #sidebar.active .CTAs {
            display: none;
        }

        #sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
            display: block;
        }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        text-align: left;
    }

    #sidebar.active ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }

        #sidebar.active ul li a i {
            margin-right: 0;
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

    #sidebar.active ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }

    #sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

        #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
            display: none;
            font-size: 1.8em;
        }

    #sidebar ul.components {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a i {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

    #sidebar ul li.active > a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #6d7fcc;
        background: #fff;
    }

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

    ul.CTAs a {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important;
    }

    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }

    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
    #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }

        #sidebar ul li a span {
            font-size: 0.85em;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a i {
            margin-right: 0;
            display: block;
        }

    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                <strong>BS</strong>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li>
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                        Pages
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this use  jquery to control style

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVbVYw

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#homeSubmenu li, #pageSubmenu li').on('click', function () {
        $('#homeSubmenu li, #pageSubmenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```